# Using Whatsapp Business API number in API and in app

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

I've recently been trying to get all messages sent and received by a Whatsapp Business account. At the moment im using the MessageBird API in order to do this, but as soon as I add the phone number in Facebook Whatsapp Manager im not able to use the number on the Whatsapp Business App. (Phonenumber is invalid)

What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is:

- Use the phonenumber in the WA Business App to send and receive messages.
- Use the phonenumber in the MessageBird API to get a list of conversations and all messages sent and received in this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Once the number is registered with WhatsApp Business API it cannot be used with the Consumer or SMB App.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/phone-number#pick-number

Comment: so What is the solution? Do i have to get a new phone number just to use whatsappbusiness on my phone?